# Ambiguous behavior of ResultSet

Tags: java, resultset

I have a requirement to create separate POJO which will set/get sql ResultSet and use its methods throughout my project code like below. I have created below 2 classes

```
    public class Tester3 
{

    public MyResultSet test() throws SQLException{
        MyResultSet mrs = new MyResultSet();
         PreparedStatement ps = null;
         String values = null;
         boolean flag = false;

         String one = "'12'";
         String two = "'jt'";
         String a = null;
         String b = null;

        try {
             if(flag==true)
             {
                values = "'3%'";
                a =null;
                b = "OR id IN(\'" +a+ "\')";
             }else
             {  
                values = "'%'";
                a = one + "," + two; 
                b = "AND id IN("+a+")";
             }

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM veracodetable where orts like PARAM RAMAN";

            sql = sql.replaceFirst("PARAM", values);
            sql = sql.replaceFirst("RAMAN", b);

            System.out.println("SQL: "+sql);

            ps = new Connection1().getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeQuery();
            mrs.setRs(ps.executeQuery());

            System.out.println("ResultSet: "+mrs.getRs().next());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mrs;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Tester3 t = new Tester3();
        MyResultSet rs = t.test();
        System.out.println("ResultSet: "+rs.getRs().next());
    }
}



 public class MyResultSet {

        ResultSet rs = null;

        public ResultSet getRs() {
            return rs;
        }
    public void setRs(ResultSet rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }
}
```

When executed above code with separate POJO **MyResultSet**, I don't get any result in ResultSet. However if I skip POJO implementation and use resultSet directly, I am able to get results.

Is **rs.getRs()** invoking at all? If not, why?

Comment: The [point of next() is to consume results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--). So each call is different. Here you most likely have one result (so 1st next = true, second one : false).

Comment: as a side note, it's a bad idea to construct sql queries like you do. You should read about sql injections and prepared statements

Comment: I am trying to fix SQL injection flaws in my code(which I cannot paste here).  Given query fetches 2 results when tried in database so shouldn't it fetch same when tried using java?

Comment: How do you know there are not 2 results when fetching using java? We don't have a [mcve] so I just explained you about `ResultSet#next()` and warned you about SQL injection the rest is pure speculation. You still can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47474271/edit) and provide your data and a [mcve] if you need more help.

Comment: Questions(not code snippet) edited.

Answer (score -1):

```
I would separate the statements as they dont't perform the same function, and then populate;

PreparedStatemet ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
if(flag){
    String stmt = "...?...?";
    ps = con.preparedStatement(stmt);
    ps.setString(0,a);
    ps.setString(1,b);
    rs = ps.executeQuery;
 }else{
    String stmt = "...?...?";
    ps = con.preparedStatement(stmt);
    ps.setString(0,a);
    ps.setString(1,b);
    rs = ps.executeQuery;
 }
}
```

Comment: Guerra: but my requirement is different so I have written like the way I pasted above

Comment: Side note: parameter indexes are 1-based in `PreparedStatement`s, see the javadoc of `setInt` for example.